# Nix: How to configure NVChad in shell.nix

Tags: neovim, nix

I am trying to use **neovim** with **nvchad** plugin. This is my **shell.nix** file so far:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  nvchad = pkgs.fetchgit {
    url = "https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad.git";
    sha256 = "sha256-7GfprTjfCrXzFiZOVw/tCB9bhA9sbNY7AicmbLXzICs=";
  };
in
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.tmux
    pkgs.python3
    pkgs.neovim
    pkgs.neofetch
    pkgs.git
    pkgs.bat
    nvchad
  ];

  shellHook = ''
    export VIMINIT='source ${nvchad}/init.lua'
    tmux
  '';
}
```

When I am launching the nvim app within nix shell, its giving me this error:

```
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /nix/store/h4mw9z5s0wmlbvnhifiwajysqbx12bwj-NvChad/init.lua:1: module 'core' not found:
        no field package.preload['core']
        no file '/nix/store/0qxy26q82jq09wjnj8ik291i6gi1y6wd-luajit-2.1.1693350652-env/share/lua/5.1/core.lua'
        no file '/nix/store/0qxy26q82jq09wjnj8ik291i6gi1y6wd-luajit-2.1.1693350652-env/share/lua/5.1/core/init.lua'
        no file '/nix/store/0qxy26q82jq09wjnj8ik291i6gi1y6wd-luajit-2.1.1693350652-env/lib/lua/5.1/core.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /nix/store/h4mw9z5s0wmlbvnhifiwajysqbx12bwj-NvChad/init.lua:1: in main chunk
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why the core module might be missing?

Comment: This doesn't directly address your problem, but putting a source tree into `mkShell`'s `buildInputs` is messy; I'd advise against it. You can still use something in the shellHook without doing so.

Comment: Yeah, it works even without putting nvchad in buildInputs. Thanks @CharlesDuffy!

Comment: (Unfortunately, I think this is more of a neovim question than a nix question, so I'm not very well-placed to answer it -- reading neovim's install docs they have expectations about install location that aren't met by the process here, and which it would be better _not to try to_ meet; is there an environment variable you can use to set the search path used looking for lua code in neovim?)

Comment: ...I suspect that perhaps amending the neovim `runtimepath` variable would help -- just a comment not an answer since (as a smug [Helix](https://helix-editor.com/) user) I'm not in a place to test.

Comment: oh, sure, will try that. Thanks for the pointers! Will try to look into this Helix editor if it has vim bindings.

Comment: Helix is usage-wise closer to [Kakoune](https://kakoune.org/) than to vim. As someone who used vim for decades, though, I'm pretty happy with it.